# Eclipse targeting different SLF4J API version than available on class path

Tags: eclipse, maven, slf4j

Several days ago, the following message started occuring every time I launch a Maven build in Eclipse IDE (v2022-12):

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/<username>/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.604.20221130-2149/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

The error occurs on each project I've tried so far (all Java/Spring). The build is being executed in the background, but no console output is generated. When launched via console the output looks like expected; so obviously only Eclipse's integrated Maven setup is affected.

I'm not aware of having changed the configuration of Eclipse or Classpath.

All hints I've found so far are focusing on fixing the SLF4J configuration for a specific (Maven) project, typically by modifying the dependencies in the POM.

How to tackle the issue for Eclipse, optimally with updating rather than downgrading SLF4J?

(Updating Eclipse is not an option at the moment, because I'm stuck with some legacy components.)

Comment: Well, the root cause actually seems to be your outdated Eclipse or, more precisely, your outdated m2e plugin. So better fix the root cause. Are you absolutely sure that the build is not executed and not just nothing is printed on the console (I would assume that the incompatibility of SLF4J versions is between the Eclipse integration and some Maven plugins). In Eclipse, does running the Maven script via an external tool work? Does running the Maven build in the current Eclipse work (your legacy components should not stop you from trying this to get more information about your issue).

Comment: Thanks for the hints @howlger. Indeed, the build is executed and just the console output is missing; I've modified the question accordingly. I'm not aware of an external tool to run Maven in Eclipse - do you have a recommendation?

Comment: _Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations..._

Comment: Just run Maven on plain command line... that's the easiest way and the cleanest as well...

Comment: @howlger When I call the Maven installed in the system as external tool it works - but there's not much difference to calling it directly via console, right?

Comment: @khmarbaise Since I have a bunch of specific settings for a bunch of projects, the IDE feature to use tested build setups as `Run configurations` is pretty useful for me.

Comment: If you have something like tests only in your IDE that violates the idea of a project which should contain all tests etc. and not in your IDE...and also specific settings ? What kind of settings are those? That sounds wrong to me...That means also if someone else clones the project does not have such setups and can not check all things...BTW: Not to talk about using a different IDE?

Comment: @khmarbaise It's perdominantly Maven profiles that need to be set correctly to build projects for different environments. Like I've said in the initial text, this question is specifically about Eclipse v2022-12; switching IDE or solving the issue thorugh upgrading Eclipse is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Building for different environments sounds wrong... violating 12/15 factor app...

Comment: Yes, running as external tool is the same as running on the command line. You have not yet answered the question whether it is working in the current Eclipse. What is stopping you from at least updating the m2e plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise This is not about building for different environments. It is about Maven in combination with the incremental compiler of Eclipse to get the advantages of both. If you run Maven on the command line or use another IDE which runs Maven before running the application or some tests, you lose the main advantage. As a Maven developer, you should value that people have this option, even if you use the command line yourself.

Comment: The line `SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation` tells you about a missing dependency... without the full log output nor the full pom it's more or less impossible to even guess.. also a very important question: Are you using OSGi ?

Comment: @howlger As expected, the issue does not occur in a fresh install of a current version of Eclipse (2023-12). I've now tried to update m2e via `Help` -> `Install new software...` where I've added used link `https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest/` to obtain a new version. At first it looked like the Eclipse installation was corrupted after updating m2e (extreme long loading time, no content in "About Eclipse IDE", etc.), but it turned out that I just needed to update and reinstall some plugins. It actually worked, IDE is working nicely, incl. Maven console output. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it is working now. Please consider to give a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution, based on updating the [Eclipse IDE integration for Maven (M2E)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-m2e-maven-support-eclipse-ide), worked for me (thanks @howlger for the support!):

- In Eclipse, go to `Help` -> `Install new Software...`
- If not in the list, add the following site: https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest/
- Select the `Maven Embedded Runtimes` (and maybe also `M2E - Complete Development Kit`)
- Follow the installation steps
- Restart Eclipse IDE
- Update/reinstall plugins if necessary